# How do I know if a envelope have reach the recipient email?

Tags: python, docusignapi

I am sending envelopes from a template to some recipients, and getting the envelope id like this:

```
while i < len(excel_signers):
    signers = {"signer_name": excel_signers[i][2], "signer_email": excel_signers[i][3], "cc_email": "emailcc@gmail.com", "cc_name": "Responsable prueba"}

    # to the template
    signer = TemplateRole(email=signers["signer_email"], name=signers["signer_name"], role_name="signer")
    # Create a cc template role.
    cc = TemplateRole(email=signers["cc_email"], name=signers["cc_name"], role_name="cc")
    envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition(template_id=args["template_id"], template_roles=[signer, cc])

    envelope_definition.status = args["status"]

    results = envelope_api.create_envelope(args['account_id'], envelope_definition=envelope_definition)

    envelope_id = results.envelope_id
    excel_signers[i] = np.append(excel_signers[i], [envelope_id]).tolist()
    i += 1
```

but then I want to know if the envelope was correctly delivered, I tried using list_status_change but it shows me "sent" in all of them which is the status I set when I send the envelope. but in the docusign's dashboard it shows "failure", how can I know when an email is not delivered?

Comment: what does "reach" mean? do you mean you want a reply-recipient confirmation from the recipient mail-server that the email was delivered? if so - I don't think that's possible
There's a way to know an email bounced, there's a way to know someone viewed an envelope (presumably saying the email reached), but I am not aware of a way to get a delivery receipt for the email from SMTP using DocuSign.

Comment: so how the docusign dashboard tells me that some email have failed?

Comment: That means the email bounced, the email server took the trouble to tell DocuSign about it. There's a negative message about bouncing emails, there's no positive message about good emails.

Comment: you could wait 2 min and if it's not bounced, assume it is good. But in some rare situations the bounce notifications take a long time...

Comment: yeah actually thats what I need, where do I check if it is bounced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the status of the recipients in your envelope use the [GetRecipientStatus](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list) endpoint of the eSignature API

Since you're using Python, you can use the Python SDK's method list_recipients()
It retrieves a lot of data about the recipients in your envelope, including their status.
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/recipients

`delivered` status means that the email to that recipient was delivered.